# What is the correct pm2 command to run wiki.js as service on windows?

Tags: node.js, windows-services, pm2

How to start and stop wiki.js from pm2 when wiki.js commands require arguments like this:

```
node wiki start // to start
node wiki stop  // to stop
```

I try to start using the command :

```
pm2 start wiki.js --node-args start
```

but in the log i got this error:

```
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [wiki] process (change the value with --line
s option)
C:\Users\cmms\.pm2\logs\wiki-out.log last 15 lines:
C:\Users\cmms\.pm2\logs\wiki-error.log last 15 lines:
0|wiki     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
0|wiki     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
0|wiki     |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
0|wiki     |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
0|wiki     |     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
0|wiki     | module.js:550
0|wiki     |     throw err;
```

Wiki.js [documentation](https://docs.requarks.io/wiki/install/installation) does not explain this part.

Comment: `pm2 start wiki.js -- start`. I.e.: everything after the `--` is passed as arguments to your program

Comment: it looks it accepts it, but now i get '0|wiki     | × Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink'. Can't find with what process the pm2 runs. Maybe i need to install 'pm2-windows-service' version instead.

Answer (score 2):

In Wiki.js 2.5.283 the correct command is:

```
cd WikiFolder
pm2 start server --name "Wiki"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct pm2 command to start wiki with name *Wiki.js* and parameter *start*:

```
 pm2 start wiki.js --name="Wiki.js" -- start
```

or without personalized name:

```
pm2 start wiki.js -- start
```

or **the easiest (most reliable)** way is to start wiki with node (it will appear in pm2):

```
node wiki start
```

than save configuration by:

```
pm2 save
```